# Dagger 2: Cannot find symbol class when using subcomponent/dependent components

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

I'm running into an issue with Dagger 2 when adding dependent/subcomponents will get me a cannot find find symbol class for DaggerAppComponent/DaggerBComponent/DaggerCComponent.

The components are like:

```
public class ApplicationComponent {
@Singleton
@Component(modules= {...})
public interface AppComponent {
    SomeManager someManager();
    void inject(Application application);
}
}

@UserScope
@Component(modules = {...}, dependencies = ApplicationComponent.AppComponent.class)
public interface BComponent{
    CComponent plus (AModule aModule, BModule bModule);
    void inject (SomeActivity someActivity);
}

@PerFragment
@Subcomponent (modules = {AModule.class,BModule.class})
public interface CComponent {
    void inject (SomeFragment someFragment);
}
```

Whenever I add the plus method to BComponent, I get the error cannot find symbol class for all 3 of the Dagger generated classes whenever I try to build. If I comment out the plus method, it does build. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What version of Dagger2 are you using?

Comment: Dagger 2.2 compiler, Dagger 2.2, with the jsr250 annotation dependency.

Comment: I wonder if updating to Dagger 2.4 would fix it, although there is a chance you have to add `apt 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'` for it to work

Comment: Can you share exact error that is giving compiler?

Answer (score 2):

I have faced same issue when the subcomponents are in a library project and I forgot to put this lines in library/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
...
...
dependencies {
    ...
    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.5'
}
```

Hope this will help you